# HTML - Jquery. Search for duplicates value in custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page which has some custom attributes. I want to make sure that the custom attributes in my code only have unique values. (Like to check for duplicate ID's but instead of checking the property name, check the property value to be unique).

Below I have posted my actual code for ID's, but I do not know how to do with attributes.

I need to make sure that my custom attributes value is unique like IDs.

```
/* Check for dobbelt ID */
checkID: function(){
    $j('[id]').each(function(){
        var ids = $j('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
        if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this){
            alert('Multiple IDs #'+this.id);
        }
    });
},


/* Check for dobbelt value in attribute. */
checkParameter: function(parmName)  {
    $j("'["+parmName+"]'").each(function(){
        var parmAttr = $j(this).attr(parmName);
            if(parmAttr.length > 1 && paramAttr[0] ){
                alert($j(this).id + "dublicates:" + parmAttr);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing now? You have typo error `parmAttr` and `paramAttr` spelling mistake.

Comment: It doesn't give me the duplicates for my custom attributes. 
It doesn't give me the alert (yes i have removed the comment from the alert in my code). 
So i'm facing that the checkParameter doesn't give me the id's from the object where the custom value has been duplicated somewhere else on the page.

Comment: Could you show us some HTML that applies to this situation?, also - Have you tried using `console.log` inside the `checkParameter()` function to see what the input to `parmName` is and if `parmAttr` actually fetches something?

Comment: When making this, i'v tried A. Wolffs solution, and it worked like a charm. 

Problem solve now, but thanks for every input. (there was also a typo error pointed out by Parth Trivedi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for duplicate custom attribute value, you can use:

```
$j("["+parmName+"]").each(function(){
    var value = $j(this).attr(parmName);
    if($j("["+parmName+"='"+ value + "']").length > 1) {
        console.log('duplicate', parmName, 'for value', value);
    }
});
```